# For loop counter variable scope seems to have a dual personality?

Tags: c#, scope

The code below produces this error in Visual Studio 2012; "A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else"

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
  {
     //something
  }
int x = 0;
```

However. When modified as below I get this error; "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context"

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
  {
     //something
  }
x = 0;
```

Is this a huge contradiction or am I missing something?

Comment: There was an Eric Lippert post about this...

Comment: @usr It was a series.  [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/05/simple-names-are-not-so-simple-part-two.aspx).  To answer the OP's question, no, it is not a contridiction.  To quote Eric's linked article, the key lies in, "it will be vital to understand the difference between scope and declaration space."

Comment: as per my understanding the first declaration will give error in any version of VS. because in .NET (OOPS) when it comes to declaration Scope does matter not the order / sequence.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So far no one except Rik has put their finger on the correct answer.

Read the error messages again, very carefully. They are clearly explaining the errors. The first error is:

> A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else

Actually *read* the error message. It says **it is illegal to use the same name to mean two different things**.  The error has nothing to do with the scope of the outer `x` per se; it has to do with the fact that `x` is used to mean *two things* in the *same outer scope*.

As Rik points out, the purpose of this rule is to avoid situations where the developer becomes confused about the meaning of `x`. A given name almost always means the same thing throughout a block. (There are some subtle exceptions but let's not go into those today.) This rule also helps prevent bugs introduced by re-ordering statements within a method and thereby subtly changing the meaning of the names. If the meaning of a name is invariant within a block then code edits within that block can be made with confidence.

A number of the answers say that scopes are not allowed to overlap. Yes they are.  **Local variable scopes** are not allowed to overlap, but **scopes** are allowed to overlap. For example:

```
class C
{
    int x;
    void M()
    {
        int y = this.x;
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {}
    }
}
```

Perfectly legal even though there are two things called `x` in scope at the same time.  But this is not legal:

```
class C
{
    int x;
    void M()
    {
        int y = x; // Means this.x
        for(int x = 0; x < 10; ++x) {} // means local x
    }
}
```

Now the simple name `x` means two different things inside the body of M, and *that* is what is illegal.  Again, make sure you understand this: **using the same name to mean two things in the same scope is what is illegal**.  It is **not** illegal to overlap scopes.

Now your second error:

> "The name 'x' does not exist in the current context"

The name `x` is only valid inside the `for` statement.  A `for` statement:

```
for (declarations ; condition ; increment ) body
```

is logically equivalent (modulo break and continue behaviour)to

```
{
    declarations;
    while(condition)
    {
        body
        increment
    } 
}
```

Note the outer braces. Anything in that declaration can be used throughout the condition, body or increment, but is not in scope outside.

Comment: Holy god.. I never thought this situation could be this much specific. And you explained it as much as simple. Thanks Eric!

Answer (score 6):

The first is an error because it is equivalent to this:

```
int x;
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
{
   //something
   // 'x' is ambiguous here
}
x = 0;
```

The way variable declarations work in C#, that is the same as your first sample.

The second is an error because the 'x' variable defined in the loop is only valid in the loop.

Comment: So you are saying that it dose not matter where the declaration is happen, it is always placed on the top of the method, right?

Comment: Sort of. You can't use a variable before you declare it, but the name you declare is reserved as if it were declared at the top of the scope.

Comment: The rule that is being violated here has nothing to do with where the outer x is in scope! Consider for example `class C { int x; void M() { int y = x; for(int x = 0; ; ) {} }`.  That's also illegal and for the same reason. But it has nothing to do with the scope of the outer `x`! Consider `class C { int x; void M() { int y = this.x; for(int x = 0; ; ) {} }` That is perfectly legal even though the outer `x` is in scope throughout!  The violation here is that the *simple name* `x` must not be used to mean two different things in the same scope, not that the scopes overlap. Scopes can overlap.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get at here, especially when you look at my prior comment: "the **name** you declare is reserved". It's whey I bothered to write the comment at all: to reply to the question about declaration location not mattering. It does matter; the scope does change, because the variable is not in scope until it's declaration. But the issue in the original question is not about the variable scope: it's about the naming conflict, and the ambiguity it creates.

Answer (score 5):

C# is stopping you from creating a confusing situation in which it is easy to make mistakes about what `x` actually refers to.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a contradiction. the `int x` you define in the `for` is scoped to the for loop, meaning:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
{
    //x is only alive here.
}

//you can't use it here.
```

however you can't create *yet another* `x` variable in a parent scope (that is, the method scope):

```
public void MyMethod()
{
   int x = 0; //method-scoped variable.

    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++)  //for-scoped variable, with the same name, invalid.
    {
        //here you have 2 "x", which one to use? invalid.
    }

   //the first x is available here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A series of statements surrounded by curly braces form a block of code. A method body is one example of a code block. Code blocks often follow a control statement. Variables or constants declared within a code block are only available to statements within the same code block.

Check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173143%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Doing this:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
  {
     //something
  }
x = 0;
```

Is detected by the semantic analyzer as an error, because x is no longer available outside the for loop.

Although when you do an int x inside of an inner block and declare a int x outside of the inner block, the compiler warns you only about a possible error in your semantics.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
  {
     //something
  }

//theoretically allowed, but the C# compiler identifies it as an error.
int x = 0; //caution x declare before
```

If you are intrigued by this, the explanation is quite simple:

As stated in the section 3.7 of the language spec. “The scope of a local variable declared in a local-variable-declaration (8.5.1) is the block in the which the declaration occurs”.

The scope of x is therefore the entire function where you declared it, and that means that the declaration/use outside the for loop is a re=use, and therefore is not allowed.

This behavior is intended to make incorrect re-use of variable names (such as in a cut and paste) less likely.

Regards.

Comment: The second example does not result in a compiler warning, it results in a compiler *error*.  That's actually a significant difference.

Comment: To be very precise, `int x = 0;` is outside the curly braces in your first example, so counting curly braces is not the key.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to child scope.

Following will not work as both `i's` are in same scope

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}

int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Following will also not work as both `i's` are still in same scope

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
int i = 10;
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Following will work just fine

```
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
{
    int i = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: This lacks an explanation as to *why*.

Comment: *You also need to know that a for-loop is treated as though there are "invisible braces" around the whole thing.* from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/confused-with-the-scope-in-c-sharp

Comment: It *is* due to child scope but you are not explaining the actual error that is being produced. See my comment to Joel's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Variable x is our of scope because it was declared in the loop. If you anyway want to use the same variable again, try this - (Not recommended though - standards wise)

```
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 9; x++){
//something
}
x = 0;
```