# Access elements of Array out side loop

Tags: c#, arrays

I have declared an integer array in which i am storing the factors of a number.....I want that array to print the number in it's elements, but I have failed too; Is there a way to access the array and it's elements outside the loop in which they are declared?

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number : ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) 
            {
                int[] factor = new int[i];

                if (num % i == 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number going in i: " + i);
                    factor[i - 1] = i;
                };
            }


            //Not working
            for (int i = 0; i < factor.length; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(factor[i]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by _failed_? Any exception or error message? Always provide much more information as possible.

Comment: Failed in the sense that its not printing, it says: The name 'factor' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `factor` in your first `for` loop only lives in the scope of the for loop. Your first loop also overwrites the array every iteration.

You need to declare and initialize it in the parent scope.

```
int[] factor = new int[num];

for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) 
{
    factor[i] ...
}

for (int i = 1; i <= factor.length; i++) 
{
    factor[i] ...
}
```

See also for example [3.7 Scopes (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx), [confused with the scope in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/confused-with-the-scope-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @JensB that should have been a comment, not an edit.

Comment: Hmm, I am new to programming pardon me If I am being stupid but if i'd write: int[] factor = new int[num];
and num = 20 lets say for example, wouldn't that create 20 elements in an array....

Comment: @aliadiere It would create an array with 20 elements, initialized to their defaults. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: Tried out and worked, thanks alot...but there are a lot of 0's too stored in the array.....Is there a way through which only factors could be stored in array, when it's in the loop; only factors were being stored...

Comment: @aliadiere sounds like you need a list, not an array. Or keep a counter which you increase each time you found a factor and use `factor[counter] = ...` when you find a match. Then don't use `i <= factor.length` in your second loop but use `i <= counter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter number : ");
        int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int[] factor ; // <-- out of for loop

        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) 
        {
           factor  = new int[i];

            if (num % i == 0) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number going in i: " + i);
                factor[i - 1] = i;
            };
        }


        //Not working
        for (int i = 0; i < factor.length; i++) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(factor[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: but then you only have access to factor in the forloop.. (scope)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter number : ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
             int[] factor ;
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++) 
            {
                factor = new int[i];

                if (num % i == 0) 
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Number going in i: " + i);
                    factor[i - 1] = i;
                };
            }


            //Not working
            for (int i = 0; i < factor.length; i++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(factor[i]);
            }

        }
    }
```

See this link about [scopes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CC8QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Faa691132%28v%3Dvs.71%29.aspx&ei=sWn8U7-wKuSp0AXIg4DwBg&usg=AFQjCNEW5nMZxqPfNQCAhFGgq7fxiTIXZw&sig2=HHlSNpuE5XHzpfagWC-bAw&bvm=bv.73612305,d.d2k)

Comment: if - int[] factor = new int[i]; is declared outside the loop how would i increment...

Comment: declare factor outside the loop and initialize it inside