# Why can't I declare a variable with the same name in different scopes in C#?

Tags: c#, scope

Not sure if this is because the C# compiler is extra picky, but I try to do this in C#:

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool result = true; // some dummy value
    if(result)
    {
        int x = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    int x = 10;
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

The compiler complains that the variable name "x" is already being used:

> A local variable named 'x' cannot be declared in this scope because it
>   would give a different meaning to 'x', which is already used in a
>   'child' scope to denote something else.

And I understand that it thinks it's a scope issue, but why does it think that?

If I reproduce the same code in Java, there are no problems.

Answer (score 2):

Not every `{}` starts a new scope.  The integer declared in the if block is still on the same stack as the function.

Comment: So you call it a duplicate and answer it at the same time..

Comment: @AlexJolig - It takes 5 votes to close and this is a valid answer.

Comment: After I did a quick answer I did a search and found a better answer.

Comment: `{}` **does** start a new scope. However that scope is of course nseted in the parent one, so it inherits its variables.

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN [Compiler Error CS0136](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/973aa6bt.aspx)

> For each occurrence of a given identifier as a simple-name in an
>   expression or declarator, within the local variable declaration space
>   (§3.3) immediately enclosing that occurrence, every other occurrence
>   of the same identifier as a simple-name in an expression or declarator
>   must refer to the same entity. This rule ensures that the meaning of a
>   name is always the same within a given block, switch block, for-,
>   foreach- or using-statement, or anonymous function.

As a second reference, check [Variable scope confusion in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/variable-scope-confusion-in-c-sharp) answers which you can find good information in.

> You are allowed to use the same variable name in non-overlapping
>   scopes. If one scope overlaps another, though, you cannot have the
>   same variable declared in both. The reason for that is to prevent you
>   from accidentally using an already-used variable name in an inner
>   scope

Answer (score 1):

As @BlackFrog correctly points out, each `{ }` does not start a new scope.  From the C# Language Specification, §3.3:

> •  Each *method declaration*, *indexer declaration*, *operator declaration*, *instance constructor declaration* and *anonymous function* creates a new declaration space called a **local variable declaration space**. Names are introduced into this declaration space through formal parameters (fixed-parameters and parameter-arrays) and type-parameters. The body of the function member or anonymous function, if any, is considered to be nested within the local variable declaration space. **It is an error for a local variable declaration space and a nested local variable declaration space to contain elements with the same name.**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more obvious why if you move the outer declaration of `x` above the if statement.

```
public static void Main()
{
    bool result = true; // some dummy value

    int x = 10;

    if(result)
    {
        //references x in parent scope
        x = 5;
        //x is already defined, can't define again
        int x = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Clearly the compiler would see `x` as being a variable which is already defined inside the if statement when the code tries to declare it again.

Comment: Yeah, and that would be the same case in Java. But order matters in Java - the example above works there. I guess the C# compiler is a little pickier.

Comment: Ah yes, forgot you said it works in Java. The java compiler obviously doesn't have the same rules as listed in the other answers.