# How to use try catch with var in C#

Tags: c#, try-catch

I have this piece of code :

```
var takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<List<Takbis>>();
ViewBag.SessionId = id;
_takbis.GetTakbisValues(takbis, vm);
```

I want to apply try-catch like this :

```
try
{
var takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<List<Takbis>>();
}
catch
{
var takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<BankReport>();
}

    ViewBag.SessionId = id;

    _takbis.GetTakbisValues(takbis, vm);
```

But I can't use it like this it says takbis does not exist in current context. I don't know the type of takbis, so I can't declare it before try catch. How can I solve this situation? Thanks.

Comment: The error message is self explanatory. You have defined it inside try which will make is in-accessible outside.

Comment: Similar to this one, but this is `for loop`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1196965/1050927

Comment: What does `GetTakbisValues` accept as parameters ? It is `object` ? If so, define `object takbis;` before the `try` can set it inside the `try` and `catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `dynamic` instead for `var` and use the code like this.  If you use `var` then the type of variable declared is decided by the compiler at compile time. but in the case of `dynamic` the type of variable declared is decided by the compiler at runtime time.

try this:

```
dynamic takbis;
try
{
   takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<List<Takbis>>();
}
catch
{
   takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<BankReport>();
}
```

Read more about the [comparison](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/460614/Difference-between-var-and-dynamic-in-Csharp)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
object takbis;
try
{
    takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<List<Takbis>>();
}
catch
{
    takbis = o.DeserializeXmlString<BankReport>();
}

    ViewBag.SessionId = id;

    _takbis.GetTakbisValues(takbis, vm);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible.
The variable must be declared outside of the try clause in order for it to be used later.

Answer (score 2):

For your information, var are processed at compile time not at run time.
Also `var` is not actually a type, its actual type is replaced by compiler. You can either check in your compiled code about the type of your `var'