# c# visibility of variable

Tags: c#, scope

I lifted some code to compare two directories, and it all works fine, but I wanted to improve it for my purposes so I can recycle the code for slightly different requirements.  The original code listed all directories, but I wanted to add in a switch so I could decide whether to list all directories or the top level only.  Here is a snippet from my code;

```
public void DoCompare(string pathA, string pathB, bool allDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(pathA);
    DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(pathB);

    if (allDirs)
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    else
    {
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    }

    //A custom file comparer defined later
    FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare();

    bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, myFileCompare);
```

Now without the if (allDirs) this works fine.  When I put that in, list1 and list 2 are not visible in the last line of code.  The actual error is "The name list1 does not exist in the current context".  I tried declaring them outside the if, but that relied on them returning results, which isn't possible without the decision.  So how do I make these visible outside the if statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable scope confusion in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/variable-scope-confusion-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not accessible because it's declared in an inner scope that is not visible in the outer scope. But you just want to change the `SeachOption` according to the `bool`, so why not simply:

```
SearchOption opt = allDirs ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", opt);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", opt);
bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, new FileCompare());
```

---

If you couldn't do that you have to declare it outside:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1;
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2;
if(allDirs)
{
    list1 = ...
    list2 = ...
}
else
{
   list1 = ...
   list2 = ...
}
// now you can access them here because they are declared in the same scope
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Neatest solution, those below and above are similar and fine, but accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

They are not accessible as they are defined in the scopes of the `if/else`. For more about [accessibility of variables in scopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

You can define them outside as in Mark's answer but instead change the if else to only take care of which `SearchOption`. That way you have no code repitition:

```
var option = allDirs ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;

IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = (new DirectoryInfo(pathA)).GetFiles("*.*", option);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = (new DirectoryInfo(pathB)).GetFiles("*.*", option);

bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, new FileCompare());
```

Answer (score 1):

Its simple, declare them outside if statement and assign inside:

```
public void DoCompare(string pathA, string pathB, bool allDirs)
{
    DirectoryInfo dir1 = new DirectoryInfo(pathA);
    DirectoryInfo dir2 = new DirectoryInfo(pathB);

    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1; // declare list1 here
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2; // declare list2 here

    if (allDirs)
    {
        list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    }
    else
    {
        list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    }

    //A custom file comparer defined later
    FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare();

    bool areIdentical = list1.SequenceEqual(list2, myFileCompare);
}
```

It's not accessible because it's declared in an inner scope that is not visible in the outer scope.

You can also simplify that method using conditional operator `?`.

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", allDirs ? SearchOption.AllDirectories : SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

Comment: @SkinnyPete63 np, you can also simplify that code with conditional operator '?'

Comment: Not a programmer, just trying to get by, so:

    list1 = (allDirs) ? dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories) : dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

?

Ha, hadn't seen the answers below.  Thanks all.

Comment: @SkinnyPete63 seems like this

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the ternary operator und change this

```
if (allDirs)
{
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
}
else
{
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}
```

to this:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list1 = allDirs?dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories):dir1.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
IEnumerable<FileInfo> list2 = allDirs?dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories):dir2.GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```