# C# unity if statement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have just started with unity, and have never used C# before. The code below raises the error `The name 'direction' does not exist in the current context` and I have no clue why. I'm sure it's super obvious but I am new to all this.

```
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

if (moveVertical != 0 || moveHorizontal != 0) {
    if (moveVertical > 0) {
        string direction = "up";
    } else if (moveVertical < 0) {
        string direction = "down";
    } else if (moveHorizontal > 0) {
        string direction = "right";
    } else if (moveHorizontal < 0) {
        string direction = "left";
    } else {
        string direction = "###";
    }

    Debug.Log(direction);
}
```

Comment: you have declared variable inside the scope and finding it in outside of the scope. check the scope of variable

Comment: You need to declare `string direction = "";` before if block. And replace `string direction` with `direction` inside if blocks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/variable-scope-confusion-in-c-sharp

Comment: You don't even need the variable, just call log in each if statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me try to explain a bit:

```
if (moveVertical > 0) {
    // You are declaring this for the if block
    // This is declared locally here
    string direction = "up";
    // Direction exists in the if block
    Debug.Log(direction);
}
// Direction does not exist here as it is out of the block
Debug.Log(direction);
```

Try to declare outside of the `if` blocks:

```
float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
string direction = "";

if (moveVertical != 0 || moveHorizontal != 0) {
    if (moveVertical > 0) {
        direction = "up";
    } else if (moveVertical < 0) {
        direction = "down";
    } else if (moveHorizontal > 0) {
        direction = "right";
    } else if (moveHorizontal < 0) {
        direction = "left";
    } else {
        direction = "###";
    }

    Debug.Log(direction);
}
```

Comment: In short: The compiler doesn't know the variable 'direction' as it is not visible outside the if-else statement.

Comment: Exaclty that! I tried to explain it with a more detailed example, but your statement sums it up perfectly.

Comment: learned something here, tks!

Comment: @H_7 I appreciate this comment more than any upvote in the world! Cheers m8.