# Referencing Variables Between Methods

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# so this is quite a noobie question; how would I reference variable **Oint** in my SQLCOMMAND method

Error: The name 'Oint' does not exist in the current context

If there are some good docs out there that go into detail on C# referencing, I would love if you could provide links.

Thank you in advance

```
     void OE()
        {
            String OE = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            if (O == "Yes")
            {
                int Oint = 1;
            }
            else if (O == "No")
            {
                int Oint = 0;
            }
            else if (O == "OLO only")
            {
                int Oint = -1;
            }
        }

        void SQLCOMMAND()
        {

            try

            {
                    String u_conn_input = textBox1.Text;
                    String conn_string = @"Server=.\" + @u_conn_input + ";Database=Test1;User Id=Test;Password=Test;Timeout=5;";
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn_string);
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("update test1..coup set oe=" + Oint + "where [Coupon Code]=\'" + textBox2.Text + "\'", con);
                    con.Open();
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "Coupon Updated" + Environment.NewLine;
                    MessageBox.Show(comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
                
            }
            catch (SqlException)
            {
                textBox3.Text = textBox3.Text + "Coupon Update Failed" + Environment.NewLine;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Make it a class member or pass it as a parameter

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please use parameterized queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variable scope confusion in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196941/variable-scope-confusion-in-c-sharp)

Comment: As well as the serious SQL injection issue, you also need to dispose your connection and command objects with `using`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: The name 'OEint' does not exist in the current context

Because each block has its own [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes), "visibility" so to speak. You could share this variable by either passing it as a [parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters) or by defining it in a [global/bigger/containing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/variables#928-local-variables) scope.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I'll need a pass by value. Thank you